# Conjugate multiplication $(4+x^2)^{\frac12}\times (4-x^2)^{\frac12}=?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm confused with what would happen after multiplying something with its conjugate.

For example, what would $\sqrt{(4+x^2)}$ multiplied by its conjugate $\sqrt{(4-x^2)}$ be?

$(4+x^2)^{\frac12}\times(4-x^2)^{\frac12} = ?$
Would the square root stay or leave?

I know this is a basic question. Please bear with me. Thank you so much!

Comment: The nice thing about roots is $\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b} = \sqrt{ab}$. So you can combine the roots, then use the third binomial theorem.

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$\left( \sqrt{4 + x^2} \right) \left( \sqrt{4 - x^2} \right) = \sqrt{(4+x^2)(4-x^2)}=\sqrt{16-x^4}.$$